# Corda - decrypt with the node's private key

Tags: corda

Is there any API for data decryption with the node's private key? Scenario: the party #1 encrypted data using party #2 public key for privacy. Now party #2 wants to decrypt the data.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption and decryption are handled by Corda Node on the platform level. Corda uses AMQP/1.0 over TLS between nodes. More details can be found @https://docs.corda.net/messaging.html